# Receive Datagram on USB/NCM Android Socket

Tags: android, networking, udp, usb, broadcast

I'm trying to receive a UDP Broadcast on the NCM0 Interface. The NCM Connection through USB is successfully established, but I don't receive anything.

I've been trying to bind the Socket to the NCM interface, but I'm getting invalid argument exceptions:

```
ArrayList<NetworkInterface>  allInterfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());

for(Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();){

NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
if (intf.getName().equals("ncm0")){
    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(intf.getInetAddresses(), 28500);
}

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.bind(addr);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
```

I've been trying to receive the Datagram like such:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

What am I doin wrong?

Comment: Is your receiving code inside a loop?

Comment: Yes it is in an infinite loop, but really only the receiving code. The socket bind only happens once.

Comment: Okay, maybe the bind failure might be caused by me, not having the NCM connection while being connected to my computer for USB debugging. I'm trying to communicate with another device. But I'm still not receiving anything...